# Why aren't self-accepted answers always on top?

Tags: discussion, voting, accepted-answer

For what reasons are self-accepted answers not on top? What can be said against sticking self-accepted answers on top that **does not apply** for other accepted answers.

Comment: Likely so the OP can't just write an answer from the answers they receive, accept it, then get all the attention (and votes) for something they didn't really do. If I had to guess.

Comment: It looks like [this has been the case since the feature was added.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/) So whatever the actual reason, it was considered even then. (I think the reason is in the comments of the blog post he links to there, but I don't have the time to scan them. If you do and find it, please post it as an answer here so we see for sure.)

Comment: Maybe it's time for this to be revisited.  I couldn't tell you what sort of "gaming" the original design was meant to protect against, so we should definitely come back to this.

Comment: I have some time now, so I'm going through those comments to see if I can pull out the reasoning. If I find it, I'll post an answer and explain it.

Comment: The biggest question is: Why are accepted answers on top at all?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There's a bit of conflict of interest: the querent is likely biased toward their own answer, even if it just barely answers their question in a way that works for them and is difficult to generalize — and similarly for answers along the spectrum from "minimally acceptable" to "excellent", where there's another answer that's even better, the querent will likely favor their own less-good answer more than would be the case for someone else's less-good answer. And taking 17 possible rep out of the equation (as is already done) isn't considered enough to outweigh the extra attention (and thus upvotes, for non-terrible answers) that being stuck to the top garners.

On the other hand, the semantics of accepting strongly suggest that it should be consistent: after all, all SE cares about is that it worked for the querent, and that's considered enough even in cases where the accepted answer has a -10 score and many comments on the reasons for its technical inferiority next to an answer with +117.

This naturally suggests the solution: [allow score differences to outweigh the checkmark if the accepted answer is downvoted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178439/can-we-exempt-downvoted-accepted-answers-from-getting-the-top-spot). (And a few variations on that.)

Comment: After reading through the comments on the blog linked by the blog I linked, I can confirm this is at least why this solution was _suggested._ I couldn't find a spot where Jeff actually explicitly said _why_ he liked that suggestion, just that he liked that one the best and felt it could work. So, this will be the best we can get, unless an employee steps in to explain.

Comment: I was going to upvote until I read, "after all, all SE cares about is that it worked for the querent." I don't think that's true. SE is design to build a repository of knowledge, through Q&A. In that light, favoring upvoted answers over the asker's self accept (except possibly for very close vote tallies) makes more sense: if the asker is expected to be biased toward their own answer, this bias would crowd out a superior answer that is useful to more users. This would hinder the goal of knowledge sharing.

Comment: In the case of accepting other users' answers, the asker is essentially stating, "This answer gave me the knowledge I needed to solve my problem," and in that case, it makes sense to feature it prominently, as other answers, no matter how heavily upvoted, were not as effective in that goal. There are, of course, cases where that doesn't hold strictly true. (I've seen some questions where I felt the accepted answer just confirmed the asker's bias and incorrectly so.) But those aren't the normal case in my experience.

Comment: @jpmc26: All SE cares about *in the context of the acceptance checkmark* is what I implied. This has been said a number of times by SE employees. In the broader scope of things, no, certainly SE cares about far more than merely the original problem or the one who framed it, which, as you point out, would make sorting by votes in most cases a better solution. My preference is to have the checkmark count for 1.5 votes (15 rep/10 rep) in the sort order to allow for tie-breaking.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Given that the functionality of the site doesn't seem to match up with that, I think it's a bit more gray than that. Sometimes, people don't quiet say exactly what they mean. And then you can glean a better understanding by looking at what they do. =) Perhaps that view has changed over time to what you describe. I can't say for sure, but I can look at what the site actually does and make educated guesses about the intentions behind it. Some links to the statements you're talking about would be appreciated, if you have them available.

Answer (score -25):

Because some people are going to try and cheat the system by asking a question that they know the answer to, then accepting their own question in order to get more reputation.

Kendra also made a good point rewriting someone else's answer should not give the asker the attention because they did not solve the problem.

Place your self in the position of someone who just spent their time trying to answer a complex question. You finally solved the question posted an answer but the person who asked the question chose their answer instead, how would you feel? Probably not good

Comment: Actually, self-answered questions are _explicitly encouraged_ by the site, so that's not the reason they aren't stuck to the top. See [this help center page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) for proof of that.

Comment: Also note that the accepted answer is _for the OP_ more than anyone else. The OP should accept the answer that helped them best- If that's theirs, great. They just won't get any extra attention for it like other accepted answers would. In the long run, if your answer is better than the self-answer, you're going to get more upvotes and therefore more reputation.

Comment: Yes, I understand that self-answered questions are encouraged. But this also allows other to receive proper the proper attention they deserve.

Comment: My self answer comment is more directed at _"Because some people are going to try and cheat the system by asking a question that they know the answer to, then accepting their own question in order to get more reputation."_ This statement makes is sound like self-answers are _completely wrong_ and should not be done. Of course, this is not the case. (And it is in no way "cheating the system" to ask and answer a question at the same time.)

Comment: Not at all, people should definitely put up the solution that helped them in order to help other people in the future. This is just an example to why self-accepted answers do not appear on top. To purposefully post a question in order to answer it and receive attention is cheating the system.

Comment: _"To purposefully post a question in order to answer it and receive attention is cheating the system"_ How do you know that the person did it to receive attention? Self-answered questions posted in such a manner are actually quite commonly done in an attempt to create a canonical question with which dupes can be closed. Also note that when you ask a question, the system _explicitly and immediately_ gives you the option to post an answer- The goal is information sharing. If this was cheating the system, the system wouldn't facilitate it.

Comment: Even if they were doing it merely to gain attention, attention received for providing useful information (as would be required to receive up-votes) is not ill-gained.

Comment: @NathanArthur: I largely agree, although the real question is whether the *additional* attention from being stuck to the top (which is potentially fairly significant) is entirely warranted. Often, multiple answers deserve upvotes, but the tedium of scrolling through and properly evaluating all of them usually greatly reduces the views on answers toward the bottom. And of course there are times that an answer or comment brings up non-obvious problems with higher-displayed answers.