# Why isn't the accepted answer the first in the list?

Tags: support

[ASP.NET Core Authorize attribute not working with JWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40646312/asp-net-core-authorize-attribute-not-working-with-jwt)

The accepted answer is the 2nd answer in the list. I thought SO used to put the accepted answer at the top, didn't it?

Regarding this question being a duplicate of [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298235/why-arent-self-accepted-answers-always-on-top). From a search point of view it cannot be, because you'd literally need to know the answer to this question in order to find that post. The answer may be the same, but the question is different.

Comment: What do you mean? The accepted answer does show on the top for that post (because it's the top voted, not because of the acceptance since its self answered). Did you order the answers by post dates?

Comment: Accepted self-answers aren't pinned and are therefore sorted like the other answers (and that's not a new change)

Comment: For me it is the 2nd answer, despite being the top voted - https://imgur.com/a/eplPa - I haven't ordered any answers, I didn't even know you could (nor do I know how).

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfNTi.jpg   Note the top, the only way you could get your result is when it's set to "oldest", if under "active" or "votes" the accepted answer should come to the top. This all being that the accepted answer is self-answered, and that it was posted the latest and had the most votes.

Comment: @abccd - Mine has no default-ordering selected - https://imgur.com/a/ZiiDk - Is that a bug?

Comment: It might be. If you believe it is, you could post another meta question tagging it as a [bug]. Be sure to check if there's already a dupe, and state all the specific specifications and possibly a way to reproduce it.

Comment: **"From a search point of view it cannot be, because you'd literally need to know the answer to this question in order to find that post"** - Why do you think it matters if you were able to find the dupe or not? And the other question also doesn't matter a single bit. The only thing that matter are the answers there.

Comment: "Why do you think it matters if you were able to find the dupe or not" - I asked why the accepted answer isn't at the top, the answer is that it is a self-accepted answer. The other question is "why aren't self-accepted answers at the top". The other question contains the answer to this question, it is not the same question.

Comment: What difference does it make? The yellow box literally says **This question already has an answer here** and you seem to agree that the answer on the other question is correct so what exactly is the problem here?

Comment: @ivarni - Maybe I am misunderstanding something. If my question is a duplicate, is it not prudent of me to delete it?

Comment: Not necessarily, it can help other people find their way to the linked question and therefore also the answer if they use search words that leads them here instead of leading them there. This question about the order of answers seems to be asked at least monthly here on meta so it doesn't hurt to have more entry-points to the answer as it would make it easier to find.

Comment: @ivarni From a psychological point I think it is likely the questioner will delete their question as the down-votes make it appear to be unwanted, and then we end up with people posting the same question again in the future.

Comment: Downvotes on meta work differently than on the main site. It's perfectly normal for questions to go in the negatives here and there are no effects on reputation due to voting at all. But if you want to delete it then that's your decision of course.